# ASPNetCacheProfile for Self Hosted WCF?

Tags: wcf, caching, rest

I think the answer is "no", but is it possible to use ASPNetCacheProfile or something equally easy to cache certain response patterns in a self-hosted WCF 4.0 REST service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Was answering some other posts for WCF when i stumbled upon this question i think this is what you are looking for http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/28/integrating-asp-net-output-caching-with-wcf-webhttp-services.aspx the answes is yes you can use ASPNetCacheProfile to cache response for WCF Rest Service